# Questions about a proof using $\omega$-covers and subsets of $\omega$

Tags: set-theory

I've been reading Galvin and Miller's article entitled "$\gamma$-Sets and Other Singular Sets of Real Numbers." Within this article is a Lemma.

> Supose $X \in [\omega]^\omega$ and $\mathcal{O}$ is an open $\omega$-cover of $[\omega]^{< \omega}$. Then, there exists $\langle D_n : n < \omega \rangle \in \mathcal{O}$ and $Y \in [X]^\omega$ such that $Y^*$ is in all but finitely many $D_n$'s.

Here:

- $[\omega]^\omega$ - the set of infinite subsets of $\omega$
- $[\omega]^{< \omega}$ - the set of finite subsets of $\omega$
- $\mathcal{O}$ is an $\omega$-cover of $X$ iff every finite subset of $X$ is contained in an element of $\mathcal{O}$
- $Y^* = \{X \subseteq \omega : Y \setminus X \mbox{ is finite } \}$

I'm having some trouble following the proof. In the proof they claim you can construct an increasing sequence $\langle k_n : n < \omega \rangle$ from $X$ and a sequence $\langle D_n :n < \omega \rangle$ from $\mathcal{O}$ such that for each $n$ and $A \subseteq \omega$, if $A \cap (k_n, k_{n+1}) = \emptyset$, then $A \in D_n$. By $(k_n, k_{n+1})$, they mean $\{ i \in \omega : k_n < i < k_{n+1} \}$.

To show this, they assume by induction that we already have the $\langle D_1, D_2, \ldots D_{n-1} \rangle$ and the $\langle k_1, k_2, \ldots k_n \rangle$ that satisfy the hypothesis. From here, they let $Q = \{ q_i : i < 2^{k_n + 1} \}$ be all the elements of $[\omega]^{< \omega}$ contained in $k_n + 1$. (so far  so good)

Now, by definition, since $\mathcal{O}$ is a $\omega$-cover of $[\omega]^{< \omega}$, there is a $D_n \in \mathcal{O}$ which covers $Q$. Now, since $D_n$ is open, there is some $k_{n-1} \in X$ such that for all $q \in Q$,

$$ \{A \subseteq \omega : A \cap k_{n+1} = q \cap k_{n+1} \} \subseteq D_n.$$

Can this be done because we can make $D_n$ big enough so that these types of subsets  of $\omega$ are included in it?

From here, they say this does the construction. I'm not sure why this completes the construction, or how this can imply $A \cap (k_n, k_{n+1}) = \emptyset \Rightarrow A \subseteq D_n$.

Next, they claim $Y = \{ k_n : n < \omega \}$ has the required properties. Is $Y$ the set of all sequences that satisfy the construction?

Then, to show $Y$ works, they say: suppose $Z - Y \subseteq k_n$ But then, for all $m > n$:$ Z \cap (k_m, k_{m+1}) = \emptyset$ and hence $Z \in D_m$. I'm not seeing how this shows $Y^*$ is in all but finitely many of the $D_n$'s.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: The condition that $D_n \in \mathcal{O}$ for $n<\omega$ seems to be missing from the statement of the lemma.

Comment: @JohnBentin Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it.

Comment: @bof Yes, it means $D_1, D_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of $\omega$-covers of $[\omega]^{<\omega}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get $k_{n+1}$, we use the fact that $D_n$ is open: For each $i$, writing $c_i$ for the characteristic function of $q_i$, this means that the cone above some initial segment of $c_i$ is contained in $D_n$. Choose $k_{n+1} \in X$ larger than the lengths of all these initial segments. It is important to remember the identification of subsets of integers by points in $2^{\omega}$ to make sense of openness in this context.

The definition of $Y^{\star}$ has a typo and $X, Y$ should be reversed there. $Y^{\star}$ is supposed to be all sets of integers which are contained in $Y$ modulo finite sets.